# How to edit and delete individual items from CRUD app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a CRUD app. I'm having trouble figuring out how to edit and delete individual items. For each item created, I'm making two `<a>` tags inside of a `<span>` tag. One for edit and one for delete. But I can't seem to figure out how to make them do what they need to do. At this point they don't do anything because I can't figure out how to access the values correctly.

Note - I'm just beginning to learn jQuery so, any pro tips on that are appreciated.

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class='form'>
            <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Type here..">
        </form>
        <h3>Notes</h3>  
        <ul></ul>
        <button id='clear'>Clear All</button>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript:

```
const app = {};

app.counter = (function(){
    var i = -1;
    return function(){
        i += 1;
        return i;
    }
})()

app.create = function(element){
    return document.createElement(element);
}

app.select = function(element){
    return document.querySelector(element);
}

app.makeList = function(text) {
    var i = app.counter();
    var li = app.create('li');

    var div = app.create('span');
    var edit = app.create('a');
    var del = app.create('a');

    li.textContent = text;

    edit.textContent = ' Edit';
    edit.href = '#'
    del.textContent = ' Delete';
    del.href = '#'

    div.appendChild(edit);
    div.appendChild(del);
    li.appendChild(div);
    ul.insertBefore(li, ul.childNodes[0])

    li.id = 'item' + i;
    del.id = 'delete' + i;
    edit.id = 'edit' + i;

}

// constants & variables

const ul = app.select('ul')
const input = app.select('input')
var notes;

$(document).ready(function(){

    if (localStorage.getItem('notes')) {
        notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes'));
    } else {
        notes = [];
    }

    localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(notes));

    // build list items and display them on the page
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes')).forEach(function(item){
        app.makeList(item);
    });

    // when form is submitted
    $('.form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (input.value.length > 0){
            notes.push(input.value);
            localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(notes));
            app.makeList(input.value);
            input.value = "";
        }
    })

    // clear items on page and from local storage
    $('#clear').click(function(){
        if (window.confirm('This will clear all items.\nAre you sure you want to do this?')){
            localStorage.clear();
            while (ul.firstChild) {
                ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild)
            }
        }
    });

    $('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){
        console.log(this.textContent) // logs whatever is typed + Edit Delete
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

```js
  $("ul").on("click", "li", function(e) {
    console.log(this.textContent); // logs whatever is typed + Edit Delete
   if(e.target.id === "edit") {
     //edit
   } 
   if(e.target.id==="delete") {
     //delete
   }
    
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access elements before they are ready that is why you are not able to see anything.

Declare them on global level but assign them value after the document is ready.

```
var ul;
        var input;
        var notes;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            ul = app.select('ul')
            input = app.select('input')
...Rest of your code
});
```

For the Edit and Delete Functionality

As you are appedning IDs in edit and delete button you need to parse that as well

```
 $('ul').on('click', 'li', function (e) {

                if (e.target.id.includes('edit')) {
                    console.log(` item ${e.target.id.split('edit')[1]} needs to be edited.`)
                }
                if (e.target.id.includes('delete')) {
                    //delete
                }
            })
```